# How to use the chromium dark mode flag (--enable-force-dark) in PySide6?

Tags: python, pyqt5, chromium, pyside6, darkmode

I am making a browser based on Chromium with PySide6 (almost the same as PyQt6).

```
import os 
import sys 

os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--enable-force-dark"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

When I run this code with the rest of my PySide6 application, it runs like normal, without any errors.

I expected the sites to be dark mode, but that is not the case. I went to chrome flags and tuned on enable-force-dark and chrome made all my websites dark mode.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I used [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/f2plcs/dark_mode_in_qt_webengine_browsers_eg_falkon_with/) for reference by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, simply remove sys.argv from QApplication().